# WIX The target file is installed in [ProgramFilesFolder] by two different components on an LFN system: This breaks component reference counting

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer

I'm using WIX to generate a .msi via TFS/MSBuild.  The error that is breaking the build (not just a warning) is:

```
ICE30:  The target file 'eiycriw9.exe|MyApp.exe' is installed in '[ProgramFilesFolder]\Folder\MyAppFolder' by two different components on an LFN system:  MyApp.exe and cmp497A0C7040B1E426AA3569D995A62AF2. This breaks component reference counting.
```

This error appears twice in the build log.

I am only installing one version of the software and there is not duplicate files.  It's a single windows application with a single .exe.

I verified unique `GUIDS` and have played with a few settings a number of times, still with no luck.  I even rolled back a bunch of things (wix files, build process template) and I still get the same error no matter what.

There is only one `<Directory Id=>` section in my WinApp.wxs file.

I am having a hard time finding info on this as most people who experience problems have multiple versions of same app in their wix files.  We do not.

Any help you can provide would be very awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Component1 and Component2 both have a file named 'READEME.1st'.
When using short file names, the installer installs both Dir1 and Dir2 to the same directory, TARGETDIR\PRODUCT.
ICE30 generate two errors, one for each file. In an authoring environment that displays error locations, the first error is at one file's entry in the File Table, and the second at the location of the other file.

----- comes from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
I have the same problem before then I found that I use the wrong value in `Source` under `Component`.