# Unable to add source files in WiX

Tags: xml, wix

I am trying to add source file into installer by WiX, but I meet the some problem and it seems there are some error in my XML file.

The error message is

> error LGHT0204 : ICE30: The target file 'FILENAME' is installed in '[ProgramFiles64Folder]\ENTERPRICE_NAME\PRODUCT_NAME\' by two different components on an LFN system: '_01152' and '_02058'. This breaks component reference counting.

It's seems the same file point to the same location, but the sources are different in my XML file as below:

```
<Component Id="_01152" Guid="GUID_NUMBER_1" Win64="yes">
  <File Id="_01152" Source=".\a\b\index.js" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
<Component Id="_02058" Guid="GUID_NUMBER_1" Win64="yes">
  <File Id="_02058" Source=".\a\c\index.js"KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

Not sure am I missing something in any attribute and hope someone who had the related experience could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK the GUIDs have to be different. So use `Guid="*"` to let WiX create an unique one.

Comment: Seems to a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130417/wix-install-the-same-file-at-two-different-locations and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832044/wix-the-target-file-is-installed-in-programfilesfolder-by-two-different-compon

Comment: Nothing to do with the source files. It's the install destinations that are most likely the same, as the error says.

Comment: Please post a larger snippet of your WiX source - we need to see your directory structure among other things. And check Phil's links.

Comment: Yes, I found the error,  that's because my destination is the same and I use `heat` to help me to generate the file and directory  structure, it might be worked.